# how can Audit All Login To SQL Server BY ODBC Connection

Tags: sql-server, audit, logins

I MAke Report By Access Form On SQL database

I make ODBC Connection For login To Update the data From Database

Now I want Audit All logins To know who make Update today Or who make Update Now ?

Any One Help ME